# Janrain Engage not working in Safari brower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, janrain, rpxnow, rpx

I've got it working in all other browsers tested -- Mac Chrome & Firefox, but it fails in Safari.  Here is the current source: http://eventchampion.heroku.com

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
<head>
<title>EventChampion</title>
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="4ZMUXRmgofgl5Z8oVXF6RbhGNrwJkieaDhmqZOeU_Mw" />
<link href="/assets/application-1c9609bc58b1e77c196de29021583379.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/application-55cd299d6f8fe22d8853de1220f2c546.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="j8Q8B/apM+we+Kv8NK5bdN216GVpw6zIMYWNWQmHRt0=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
<p class='notice'></p>
<p class='alert'></p>
<div id='janrainEngageEmbed'><a class="rpxnow" href="https://EventChampion.rpxnow.com/openid/v2/signin?token_url=%23%3Fauthenticity_token%3Dj8Q8B%252FapM%252Bwe%252BKv8NK5bdN216GVpw6zIMYWNWQmHRt0%253D">Sign In</a></div>
<h1>Home#index</h1>
<p>Find me in app/views/home/index.html.haml</p>

      <script src="https://rpxnow.com/openid/v2/widget" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        //<![CDATA[
        RPXNOW.token_url = 'http://eventchampion.heroku.com/users/sign_in?authenticity_token=j8Q8B%2FapM%2Bwe%2BKv8NK5bdN216GVpw6zIMYWNWQmHRt0%3D';
        RPXNOW.realm = 'EventChampion';
        RPXNOW.overlay = true;



        //]]>
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed a config setting from app_name = "AppName" to app_name = "appname" solved